# Why are markings of \$R_1\$ displayed everywhere in the circuit?

Tags: circuitikz

The marking of $R_1$ is display everywhere.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}  % for drawing pictures
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} 


\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american,]
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\def\killdepth#1{{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{#1}}}
%\path (0,0) -- (2,0); % bounding box

\draw 
(-3,9)  -- (3,9) node[label=right: $V_{dd} \SI{}{}$] {}

(2,9) to [resistor, a^ = $R_3$] (2,5)



%(M1.gate) -- (3,-1) -- (-3,-1)[short, -] to (-3,0) coordinate (A)

%(-3,1)[short, *-] to (M1.gate) 

(2,5) -- (-3,5) to [resistor, a^ = $R_2$] (-3,3)
 to (-3,3) [resistor,a^ = $R_1$] (-3,3)
to (-3,1.5) node[ground](GND){} 



(2,1) node[nmos] (M1) {$M_1$}
(M1.source) node[] {} -- (2,0) node[ground](GND){} (2,-3)

 (2,4)node[nmos] (M2) {$M_2$} 
(0,4) node[anchor=east] {$V_{bias}$}[short, o-] to (M2.gate) node[] {}
(M2.source) node[] {} -- (2,2)
(M2.drain) node[right] {} -- (2,5) to  [short, *-o, name=S] ++ (2,0) node[right]{$V_{out}$};

\draw (-3,3.25)[short, *-] to (-4,3.25) -- (-4,2) node[ground](GND){};

\draw (5,0) node[ground](GND){}  to (5,0) to [I, i_>=$I_{in}$]  (5,2) to (2,2)[short, *-*];
%\draw  [short, -](5,1) to  [short, *-*, name=S] ++(3,0)node[right]{$V_{out}$};

%\draw  [short, *-] (-2,0) to [resistor, a = $R_2$] (-2,-3);   

%\draw (5,6) to (5,4) node[nmos] (M2) {$M_2$} (5,3) to (5,1);
   
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Current-Voltage Feedback After loop break} \label{fig:curr_volt_break_loop}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I remove those unnecessary $R_1$ markings which are circled with red in my circuit?

Comment: This looks like a bug, report it at [`circuitikz`' issue tracker](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues). For now, you can remove the spurious labels by passing the option `a=` (i.e. an empty annotation) to the two `to` where they appear (lines 41 and 43 of your MWE).

Comment: BTW, one can use `[l=...]` instead of `[a^=...]`.  Label (l) is the older option.

Comment: No, it's not a bug. You can't use `to (coord) [resistor...] ...`, the path option must be arguments of `to`, otherwise they apply globally to the path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have several errors in your code. The R₁ thing is due to

`to (-3,3) [resistor,a^ = $R_1$] (-3,3)`

where the `[]` options are not applied directly to the `to` command, so that they are global to the (sub)path. Remove the first (by the way, redundant) coordinate and the $R_1$ will stick with the resistor.

Then, you are using `node [] {}` all over the place, which does nothing here but could create unwanted spaces (remember that a node has a non-zero size, look at the FAQ in the `circuitikz` manual).

Then, you do not have sufficient space for the R₁/R₂ thing.

The last plot, with a `[short, *-*]` without a `to`, is again not correct.

Finally, I think you miss a connection with the M₁ drain.

I did a minimal correction (the circuit code could be greatly improved), but I do not know if this is what you wanted.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}  % for drawing pictures
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american,]
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\def\killdepth#1{{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{#1}}}
%\path (0,0) -- (2,0); % bounding box

\draw
(-3,9)  -- (3,9) node[label=right: $V_{dd} \SI{}{}$] {}

(2,9) to [resistor, a^ = $R_3$] (2,5)



%(M1.gate) -- (3,-1) -- (-3,-1)[short, -] to (-3,0) coordinate (A)

%(-3,1)[short, *-] to (M1.gate)

(2,5) -- (-3,5) to [resistor, a^ = $R_2$] (-3,3)
 to [resistor,a^ = $R_1$] (-3,1)
node[ground](GND){}



(2,1) node[nmos] (M1) {$M_1$}
(M1.source) -- (2,0) node[ground](GND){} (2,-3)

 (2,4)node[nmos, ] (M2) {$M_2$}
(0,4) node[anchor=east] {$V_{bias}$}[short, o-] to (M2.gate) 
(M2.source)  -- (2,2) 
(M2.drain)  -- (2,5) to  [short, *-o, name=S] ++ (2,0) node[right]{$V_{out}$};

\draw (-3,3.25)[short, *-] to (-4,3.25) -- (-4,2) node[ground](GND){};

\draw (5,0) node[ground](GND){}  to [I, i_>=$I_{in}$]  (5,2) to (2,2) -- (M1.D) ;

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]