How can I avoid two black dot in the circuit?
Here is the circuit code.
I only want black dot at the intersection. However, it's at both end of the line segment.
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % piecewise equation
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{gensymb} % degree package
\usepackage{siunitx} % Unit Package
\usepackage{relsize} % Make math symbols bigger
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % change the `enumerate` list format to use letters instead of the default Arabic numerals
\usepackage{pgfplots}               % plot digram package
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}  % for drawing pictures
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % drawing arrow for voltage over resistor |<-  5 V  ->|


\usepackage{ctable} % for \specialrule command

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american, dbx/.style={dashed, draw},
fbt/.style={anchor=east,align =center,pos=0.4,font=\bfseries, below=0 cm},]
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\def\killdepth#1{{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{#1}}}

\draw 
(-3,9)  -- (3,9) node[label=right: $V_{dd} \SI{}{}$] {}

(2,9) to [resistor, a^ = $R_{D}$] (2,6)
(2,5) node[nmos] (M1) {$M_1$}
(2,6) to (M1.drain)

 node[left]{$V_{in}$} [short, o-] (-7,5)  to [resistor, a^ = $R_{S}$]  (-4,5)  to (M1.gate)

(M1.source)  -- (2,4) node[ground](GND){};
    
    \draw (-4,5)[short, *-] to (-4,6.5)  
     (-4,6.5) to [resistor, a^ = $R_{F}$] (-2,6.5)
     (-2,6.5) -- (-2,6.5) node[ground](GND){};
  \draw (-1,6.5)[short, o-*] to [resistor, a^ = $R_{F}$] (2,6.5);

\draw     (2,6.5) to  [short, -o]  (4,6.5) node[right]{$V_{out}$};


\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Voltage-Voltage Feedback network in Miller effect} \label{fig:volt_volt_loop}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



The problem is not a duplicate. Why can't I use ?
\draw   [short, -o]  (4,6.5) to ...;


This is basic a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713955/38080. Every path-style circuitikz key MUST be in the optional argument of a to command...

In the duplicate answer, I literally say (after explaining why): "The last plot, with a [short, *-*] without a to, is again not correct."  The only difference is the type of poles involved, so I still think it's a duplicate. Basically,  every path-style circuitikz key (like short) MUST be in the optional argument of a to command... If you can find a case in the 200+ pages manual where this is not done, please open a bug, I'll correct it asap.

The options should be placed after the to command. Otherwise, the options are applied to every line of the path.
Here is an example:
\draw (-4,5) to [short, *-] (-4,6.5) to [resistor, a^ = $R_{F}$] (-2,6.5) node[ground](GND){};



Take a look at my update

It's still the same problem and the same solution. In line 49 replace ... [short, *-] to ... by ... to [short, *-] .... Additionally, I recommend to not duplicate each coordinate.
